# Xcode9 iOS export archive fails on correct format

Tags: ios, react-native, xcode9

I have an iOS app that is building on both xcode8 (Sierra) and on xcode9 (High Sierra).

When I'm doing exportArchive it passes on xcode8 but fails on xcode9.

I have the provisioningProfiles section in my plist, and the failure in on correct format.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
    <key>method</key>
    <string>enterprise</string>
    <key>teamID</key>
    <string><Our teamID></string>
    <key>signingStyle</key>
    <string>manual</string>
    <key>signingCertificate</key>
    <string><Our signingCertificate></string>
    <key>provisioningProfiles</key>
    <dict>
        <key><Our bundleID></key>
        <string><App Name></string>
    </dict>
</dict>
</plist>
```

I have another app that I'm building and everything is fine. Both xcode8 and xcode9. All the IDs are correct.

This the error that I'm getting:

```
2018-04-11 02:16:07.014 xcodebuild[25609:10463244] [MT] IDEDistribution: Step failed: <IDEDistributionPackagingStep: 0x7fe89376c690>: Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=3840 "No value." UserInfo={NSDebugDescription=No value., NSFilePath=/var/folders/y0/5_70v74n4830lyzmjs08pm4w0000gn/T/ipatool-json-filepath-KoS1w8}
[09:16:07][iOS: Build release version] ** EXPORT FAILED **
[09:16:07][iOS: Build release version] error: exportArchive: The data couldn’t be read because it isn’t in the correct format.
[09:16:07][iOS: Build release version] 
[09:16:07][iOS: Build release version] 
[09:16:07][iOS: Build release version] Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=3840 "No value." UserInfo={NSDebugDescription=No value., NSFilePath=/var/folders/y0/5_70v74n4830lyzmjs08pm4w0000gn/T/ipatool-json-filepath-KoS1w8}
```

Thanks.

Comment: What is in the `/var/folders/y0/5_70v74n4830lyzmjs08pm4w0000gn/T/ipatool-json-filepath-KoS1w8` file?

Comment: The file is not there when I searched for it.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I was facing the similar error, You can try to append following key-pair. This had fixed my error.

```
<key>compileBitcode</key>
<false/>
```

Comment: Added the above key-pair in exportOption.plist and it solved the error.
Looks like having multiple Xcode version on the same system causes the error.

Comment: Awesome. You saved my day.

Answer (score 2):

In my case was an issue with rvm I fixed it following the instructions on this blog entry:

https://egeek.me/2018/04/14/ipa-export-error-in-xcode-and-ruby/

Answer (score 0):

For those who experience this error while use `fastlane`, add to `gym`

```
      export_options: {
        compileBitcode: false
      },
```

option

[Discussion thread](https://github.com/fastlane/fastlane/issues/10133#issuecomment-326039273)